# Random string added end of the url blog page wordpress

Tags: urls

```
https://example.com/blog/page/2/?et_blog
```

The random text appeared end of the URL I have to remove (?et_blog)  that I am using Divi theme for WordPress.

Comment: Did the DIVI support staff give you any info?  Try deactivating plugins and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

"The pagination links have the ?et_blog parameter to avoid the pagination clashes with the main query. It has no impact on SEO since the URL's have the "canonical" URL set to the main page."

from:

https://intercom.help/elegantthemes/en/articles/2912512-how-to-disable-ajax-in-the-blog-module